# Refreshing the page with a Heroku Python app

Tags: python, heroku, jinja2, watch

This is the first time I have asked a question, so please forgive me if I leave something out.

I am working on my first app using Heroku, this is a python app. When working locally I would like to be able to see changes without having to restart the server. I know in node there is a way to run the server so that changes are live. Any advice on add-ons or how to reword my search for this would be greatly appreciated (I have tried searching for "live changes to heroku python", "heroku watch", "automatic restarting of heroku server" and a few other things).

The CSS updates with a refresh, but any text added or other changes will not update without restarting the server. I am using Jinja2 for templating.

Currently to run the server I am using `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What framework are you using?  Django (which I expect you're not using given you're using jinja2 for templating and Django has its own similar templating language) can do the live updates via its built in runserver; I would expect flask and others can as well, but you'd need to specify

Comment: If you're using Flask, you can set `app.debug = True` and it should let you make those updates and view them without restarting the server.